# History of imperative in hypotheses

Tags: math-history

In mathematical hypotheses it is traditional to use the imperative instead of a declarative sentence.

> What is the origin of this tradition? Does it go back to ancient Greek mathematics? Or maybe to Bourbaki?

This is clearly a usage that exists in different languages:

> Let $n$ be an integer ...
>   Soit $n$ un entier ...
>   Sei $n$ eine ganze Zahl ...

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Absolutely not. All the definitions I can recall are either of the form "$X$ is $Y$" or "We say $X$ if $Y$". Even the first line of Euclid is declarative: Σημεῖόν **ἐστιν**, οὗ μέρος οὐθέν.

Comment: The examples you have cited are not really definitions; rather, they are _hypotheses_.

Comment: @ZhenLin You are right, I will edit my question.